# Guava-collections and jackson-datatype-guava gradle conflict. (com.android.dex.DexException)

Tags: android, jackson, guava, android-gradle-plugin, dex

i added `'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3'` module and `'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.4.3'` to my android app project which use 
 `'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'` module.

However as i try to build the APK i get this errror:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/annotations/Beta;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I runned `gradlew -q :app:dependencies` which result is:

```
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 -> 21.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+ -> 21.0.2
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+ -> 21.0.2 
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
+--- com.eowise:recyclerview-stickyheaders:0.5.0
+--- project :library
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0 -> 21.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava-primitives:r03
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-base:r03
|              \--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
\--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.4.3
     +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3
     |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
     +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
     \--- com.google.guava:guava:15.0
```

So, the problem seems to be that my project uses guava module two times, one time in "jackson-dataype" and one time in "guava" module. I tried to exlude guava module from jackson-datatype with

`compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.4.3'){
        exclude module: 'guava'
    }`

but this results in a `Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK` which suggests me to

`ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      }
    }`

well, as i do this i get this while trying to sync gradle: 
`Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()'`

I'm stuck there, I'm sure i've got something wrong but i can't figure out what.

Finally, these are my gradle dependencies if needed:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.eowise:recyclerview-stickyheaders:0.5.0@aar'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3'
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.4.3'){
        exclude module: 'guava'
    }
    compile   files('C:/.../mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-3.jar')
}
```

Comment: can you show all your build.gradle file ?

Comment: you can fix this issue by removing `compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'` this is actually very old  version of this library. Also you could remove all libs folder dependencies and replace them by gradle dependencies - gradle will resolve duplicates in your dependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I fixed the issue using only the module 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.4.3' and adding to android{} the lines: packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }. It now builds fine.